VSCode warns about active terminal sessions that do not exist
I am using VSCode Remote Extension to connect to my VM, when I try to reload the window, it always shows this warning:
"Do you want to terminate the 6 active terminal sessions?"

However, I don't have any open terminal sessions. I suspected the port forwardings, but there are only two of them.
How can I find out what are these open terminal sessions?
I tried sudo ss -tnp | grep sshd to see open ssh connections but there was only two of them.
These are my list of extensions:
code --install-extension Extensions installed on SSH: Dev:
code --install-extension github.copilot
code --install-extension github.copilot-chat
code --install-extension ms-python.black-formatter
code --install-extension ms-python.debugpy
code --install-extension ms-python.python
code --install-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance
code --install-extension redhat.java
code --install-extension visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
code --install-extension visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-gradle
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-debug
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-pack
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-test
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-maven

My VSCODE is updated. I am connecting to it from Windows and my remote VM is running Ubuntu.
